# Keep Highligh on Parent <a> when hovering on Child <a> in a dropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

Im working on a dropdown menu, and i want my Parent `<a>` to "keep its color" when i move to a child `<a>`.

I know how i could do it by using hover on my `<li>` with something like:
`ul#nav li:hover > a`. but that wont work here, cause i only want hover on my `<a>`'s...

Hope you understand my problem

Heres my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F623k/7/

Answer (score 0):

Used to this

```
    ul#nav > li:hover > a {
        color: #ff7800;
    }
ul#nav li ul li a:hover {
        color: #ff7800;
    }
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/F623k/10/)***